# GET WooCommerce customers based on "date_modified"

Tags: request, woocommerce-rest-api, user-data

I am looking to GET all WooCommerce customers that have created or modified their profile since last request using the WooCommerce REST API.

I know that "date_modified" is not a parameter listed here https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-customers but I thought that I could make it a queriable parameter.

OR can I do this with a custom field of some sort?